# Se me esta agregando un margen en el contenedor grid

Tags: css, bootstrap

Se me está agregando un padding a los lados en el contenedor grid que no me permite centrar el contenido. Estoy usando *css grid* y *bootstrap*; no sé si es algo añadido por *bootstrap* pero no me permite quitarlo. Estoy usando [normalize-css](/questions/tagged/normalize-css) también.

[image: los bordes entre la seccion es el problema]

```
body {
  background-color: #AEA7A7 !important;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.header .logo a {
  font-family: 'Pacifico',sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header form input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.header form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.header form input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.header form input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.header form input::placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.header form i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.header .nav-bar a {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif;
}

.header .nav-bar i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: white;
}

.header .btn-i {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: black;
}

.header .btn-r {
  background-color: #218F84;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  header .burgers {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .nav-bar {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-bar.show {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  .nav-bar.show .btn-i {
    padding: .7rem;
    font-size: .9rem;
  }
  .nav-bar.show .btn-r {
    padding: .7rem;
    font-size: .9rem;
  }
  .nav-bar.show i {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
  .header {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
  }
  .burgers {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .burgers:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  .logo {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header form i {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .burgers {
    display: none;
  }
}

.categorias {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.categorias .title {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin-top: 0rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #585757;
}

.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .grid {
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

.link {
  background-color: #aa1414;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: .8rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.link:hover {
  color: white;
}

.negocios {
  background-color: #238acf;
}

.negocios:hover {
  background-color: #1c6da3;
}

.naturaleza {
  background-color: #23cf5c;
}

.naturaleza:hover {
  background-color: #1ca349;
}

.historia {
  background-color: #cfbe23;
}

.historia:hover {
  background-color: #a3961c;
}

.ciencia {
  background-color: #4823cf;
}

.ciencia:hover {
  background-color: #391ca3;
}

.amor {
  background-color: #cf2923;
}

.amor:hover {
  background-color: #a3201c;
}

.dinero {
  background-color: #239ecf;
}

.dinero:hover {
  background-color: #1c7da3;
}

.pasion {
  background-color: #cf2348;
}

.pasion:hover {
  background-color: #a31c39;
}

.documentales {
  background-color: #45b369;
}

.documentales:hover {
  background-color: #378e53;
}

.informatica {
  background-color: #236ecf;
}

.informatica:hover {
  background-color: #1c57a3;
}

.salud {
  background-color: #cfb523;
}

.salud:hover {
  background-color: #a38f1c;
}

.card {
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  border: none !important;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.card img {
  height: 230px;
}

.card .book {
  color: #585757;
  font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card .autor {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #C4C4C4;
  font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.card .stars {
  color: #FFDD01;
}
```

Comment: No veo ningún margen en tu captura, eso es un padding, y está claramente designado en tu css "padding: 1.5rem 3rem;" aparte que no has puesto el código mínimo verificable

Comment: Hola, he quitado el padding y me sigue saliendo asi

Comment: No muestras el parte del html, y no explicas como has quitado el padding, yo lo veo en tu css, asi es complicado ayudarte

Comment: Buenas, agrega el html para crear el [mre] y resolver tu problema

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres es quitar el padding de los lados del grid, solo tienes que cambiarlo a como lo dejo a continuación:

Para saber mas de como funciona el padding te dejo esta pagina donde lo explican con un ejemplo muy comprensible https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/padding

```css
.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
}
```

Comment: Procura hacer un breve resumen de lo que hace el código, y lo mismo cuando adjuntas enlaces: recuerda que el contenido del mismo puede que ya no esté disponible más adelante, invalidando así la respuesta. Lee [answer] y de paso haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so].